# With System.Runtime.Caching, is there a physical location where the cache is stored?

Tags: .net, memorycache, objectcache

I was wondering if there is a physical location the cache is stored at and if so, can the location be changed?

Comment: define "physical location" in this context? the *default* is "in RAM"; RAM is undoubtedly physical in some sense, but I don't think it would help...

Comment: By physical location, I mean location on disk.  If there is, I'm wondering if I can change the location to something like D:\Inetpub\Cache

Comment: From the first page of the documentation. You can create custom caching providers. For example, instead of using the default in-memory cache engine, you can create custom providers that store cache data in databases, in custom objects, or in the file system. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx

Comment: @ijason03 the default implementations *don't use disk*